# After data & background image load from Angular http call

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, angularjs

In my controller I have an http call like so:

```
$http.get("/api/content").success(function(data){
  $scope.entry = data;
});
```

`$scope.entry` now looks like this:

```
{
  name: "Test name",
  about: "Some information here",
  image: "//www.example.com/my-image.jpg"
}
```

Now I render the results in my HTML like so:

```
<div class="block">
  <div>{{entry.name}}</div>
  <div>{{entry.about}}</div>
  <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + entry.image + ')'}"></div>
</div>
```

Works great. Now I only want the block to show after the http call has completed, the text applied to the scope and rendered in the HTML, and the background image loaded. So basically when the block has fully loaded, it can then display.

So I initially set CSS to hide the block, then want to apply a class to the block when it's ready:

```
.block {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 300ms; }

.block.ready { opacity: 1; }
```

My question is, how do I detect when the background image is loaded?
I have a lot of these blocks on my site, all with different content, so I'll need to do this multiple times.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages will helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make use of `ng-show`. Just make it true in the $http callback.

```
<div class="block" ng-show="show">
  <div>{{entry.name}}</div>
  <div>{{entry.about}}</div>
  <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + entry.image + ')'}"></div>
</div>
```

In $http callback:

```
$http.get("/api/content").success(function(data){
  $scope.entry = data;
  $scope.show=true;
});
```

Comment: But this only waits for the data from the http request i.e. the url string. It hasn't actually waited for the url to load as a background-image...

Answer (score 0):

Put the html in ng-if 
like

```
<div class="block" ng-if="flag">
  <div>{{entry.name}}</div>
  <div>{{entry.about}}</div>
  <div ng-style="{'background-image':'url(' + entry.image + ')'}"></div>
</div>


$scope.flag=false;
$http.get("/api/content").success(function(data){
  $scope.entry = data;
  $scope.flag=true;
});
```

so that It would create block when response will come

Comment: Doesn't this only wait for the data to come through? I'm looking to know when the image has actually loaded. On a slow connection, you would still see the image loading on the screen with this method.

Comment: you can show a loader while image is not loading . <div id="loader"         ng-if="!flag"> which means when value comes true it will hide and it will show image .

Comment: You don't understand my question. In your answer, `$scope.flag` will turn true and show `.block` when the data comes through from the http request.  But after the block shows, on a slow connection, the image may take another 1 or 2 seconds to actually render in the browser. The URL will be in the inline styling but it takes time to render.

Comment: I got your point ..when the image is large it will take to render so you can put some delay with flag value ,but it is obivious that it may show early before rendering because angular could check its scope variable value where as it wont be able to check whether how much html has been rendered